# BooleanBinding with depending elements

Tags: javafx, binding

I would like to create boolean bindin like that :

```
    BooleanBinding binding = Bindings.createBooleanBinding(
            () -> (context.getService() == null
                    || context.getService().getCurrentFamily() == null),
            context.serviceProperty(), context.getService().familyProperty());
```

But at the moment of initialization the  value of serviceProperty is null so I receive the NullPointerException on `context.getService().familyProperty()`

How can i initialise this binding. correctly  ?

Comment: You have a more fundamental problem: the binding will only bind to the *current service's* `familyProperty`. If the service changes (which presumably it can, since you bind to `context.serviceProperty()`), you will still be bound to (observing changes on) the *old* service's `familyProperty()`, not the new service's `familyProperty()`. Consequently, even if you fix the problem with the NPE, after the service changes, changes to the service's family will not update the binding.

Comment: jeah.. you're right .. so I must initialise 2 Listeners to listen. Service change and  within family changes...  thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the standard API, you can do

```
BooleanBinding binding = Bindings.select(context.serviceProperty(), family).isNull();
```

This has a nasty habit of generating warnings on standard output if the service (in this example) is null, though it will still work correctly despite those warnings. For use cases such as these, I like Tomas Mikula's [EasyBind](https://github.com/TomasMikula/EasyBind) or [ReactFX](https://github.com/TomasMikula/ReactFX) libraries. For example, with ReactFX 2.0 you can do something along the lines of

```
ObservableValue<Boolean> binding = 
    Val.map(context.serviceProperty(), service -> service.familyProperty())
        .flatMap(family -> family.isNull());
```